# Magento 2.4.2: [Report Only] Refused to load the script 'https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net

Tags: magento2.2, frontend, google, csp

One of a few content security policy directive issues seen in the console when visiting a product page is what reads on below.

```
[Report Only] Refused to load the script 'https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/viewthroughconversion/763933772/?random=1652000039511&cv=9&fst=1652000039511&num=1&label=9pwQCPSv87kBEMzoouwC&bg=ffffff&guid=ON&resp=GooglemKTybQhCsO&u_h=720&u_w=1280&u_ah=690&u_aw=1280&u_cd=24&u_his=2&u_tz=330&u_java=false&u_nplug=5&u_nmime=2&gtm=2wg540&sendb=1&ig=1&frm=0&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmagento2.perfectmakeupmirrors.com%2Fmirror-image-helix-5x1x-chrome-black-vanity-mirror.html&tiba=Kimball%20%26%20Young%20Mirror%20Image%2080735%205x%2F1x%20reversible%20makeup%20mirror%20has%20a%20unique%20chrome%20and%20black%20frame.&hn=www.googleadservices.com&async=1&rfmt=3&fmt=4' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src assets.adobedtm.com secure.authorize.net test.authorize.net www.googleadservices.com www.google-analytics.com www.paypalobjects.com js.braintreegateway.com www.paypal.com geostag.cardinalcommerce.com
```

To fix it by whitelisting the domain, I added the entry below in CSP module's csp_whitelist.xml file. Despite that, the issue still remains. Please share your suggestions or advices if it has to be fixed in a different way.

```
<value id="googleads" type="host">googleads.g.doubleclick.net</value>
```

Comment: hey @CodeForGood did you find any solution?

Comment: No, I left the issue as is. Any suggestion from your end?